# Sorting An Array - Where do comparisons and swaps take place?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

> Examine the given Python source code for insertion sort and selection sort. Run the 
>   code on some small examples to demonstrate that both correctly sort the given 
>   input.
>
> Instrument (modify) both programs to count the number of comparisons of the data 
>   elements during the sorting process. Record the number of comparisons of each 
>   sort for each of the three input files for 100, 200, 400 and 800 lines of input.
>   Continue to modify each of the sorting algorithms to count the number of swaps of 
>   data elements.
>
> Record the number of swaps for the same set of inputs as earlier.
>   Turn in your modified source code and your recorded number of comparisons and 
>   swaps.

I am trying to combine Insersion Sort and Selection Sort so the program will spit out all the answers I need with one run.  Here is my current code.

```
import sys

def IS(a,length):
ISComp = 0
ISSwap = 0
minindex = 0
for i in range(1,length,1):
    if (a[i] < a[minindex]):
        minindex = i
a[0],a[minindex] = a[minindex],a[0]

for i in range(2,length,1):
    ISComp += 1
    j = i
    value = a[j]
    while (value < a[j-1]):
        a[j] = a[j-1]
        j = j-1
    a[j] = value
    ISSwap += 1

return(ISComp, ISSwap)

def SS(a,length):
SSComp = 0
SSSwap = 0
for i in range(0,length-1,1):
    minIndex = i
    for j in range(i+1,length,1):
        if (a[j] < a[minIndex]):
            minIndex = j
            SSComp += 1
    temp = a[i]
    a[i] = a[minIndex]
    a[minIndex] = temp
    SSSwap += 1

return(SSComp, SSSwap)

def main():
print("Working with File 1...")
file = open("file1","r")
print("For 100 lines of data:")
stringArray = []
for i in range(0,100,1):
    stringArray.append(int(file.readline()))
(isc, iss) = IS(stringArray, 100)
(ssc, sss) = SS(stringArray, 100)
print(str(isc) + " InsersionSort Comparisons, ", str(iss) + " InsersionSort Swaps")
print(str(ssc) + " SelectionSort Comparisons, ", str(sss) + " SelectionSort Swaps")

print("For 200 lines of data:")
stringArray = []
for i in range(0,200,1):
    stringArray.append(int(file.readline()))
(isc, iss) = IS(stringArray, 200)
(ssc, sss) = SS(stringArray, 200)
print(str(isc) + " InsersionSort Comparisons, ", str(iss) + " InsersionSort Swaps")
print(str(ssc) + " SelectionSort Comparisons, ", str(sss) + " SelectionSort Swaps")
main()
```

The problem is, I'm not sure where to add ISSwap, ISComp, etc. so that it gives me the right answers when I run the program.  Where do the comparisons and swaps take place for each of the functions?